# Fold expressions and empty parameters pack: what's the expected result?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, fold-expression

Consider the following minimal example:

```
#include<cstddef>

template<std::size_t... I>
constexpr auto sum() { return (I + ...); }

template<bool... B>
constexpr auto check() { return (B && ...); }

int main() {
    static_assert(6 == sum<1,2,3>(), "!");
    // static_assert(0 == sum<>(), "!");
    static_assert(check<true, true>(), "!");
    static_assert(check<>(), "!");
}
```

The commented line doesn't compile.
The same applies using `*` instead of `+`.
The one involving booleans works instead.

[Here](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.fold) (working draft) I haven't found mentions about empty parameter packs.
On the other side, [here](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n4295.html) (isocpp) it seems that the default result in the case above is `int()`.

What's exactly the expected behavior when mixing fold expressions and an empty parameters pack?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is covered in [[temp.variadic]¶9](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.variadic#9) (citing N4618):

> If `N` is zero for a unary fold-expression, the value of the expression
>   is shown in Table 14; if the operator is not listed in Table 14, the instantiation is ill-formed.
>
> **Table 14 — Value of folding empty sequences**:
>
> ```
> Operator  |  Value when parameter pack is empty  
> -----------------------------------------------
> &&        |  true
> ||        |  false
> ,         |  void()
> ```

The reason only these three operators are supported is outlined in [P0036R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0036r0.pdf).

Comment: I'd be curious to know why these operators were singled out as opposed to making them all ill-formed.

Comment: @Borgleader : See [P0036R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0036r0.pdf). However [P0160R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0160r0.html) says that defaults for empty parameter packs were resolved to be removed entirely; I'm not sure what changed or why this isn't reflected in the current draft.

Comment: @ildjarn That didn't get consensus in plenary, so eventually they voted P0036 in instead.

Comment: @T.C. : Thank you! I see that now in the [Kona minutes](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4558.html) paper; for future reference, is there an easier source to see such vote results, or are the minutes papers the best place to look?

Comment: @downvoter : As per SO etiquette, if you're going to downvote an answer (which should only be if it's ["*egregiously sloppy, \[a\] no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect*"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)), leave an explanation as to _why_ you're downvoting so that the answer can be improved if necessary.

Comment: @ildjarn Actually it doesn't make much sense to downvote your question. I'm voting it up to compensate. Can you integrate the answer with the links posted in the comments? I think they are useful to fully cover the topic. Thank you.

Comment: @ildjarn The minutes is still the best publicly available place to look AFAIK.

Comment: @ildjarn  There are four users actually named downvoter.  Which of them were you talking to and how did you know it was them that downvoted the answer?